# How to filter point clouds by creating a retangle with touches on a Tango phone

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am scanning 3D objects using tango. Now I touches 4 points on the screen to make a rectangle and then remove all point clouds outside this rectangle.

But I have checked the "Point To Point" example provided in the Tango SDK but I do not understand the relationship between point clouds and touch position on the screen. In the "TangoPointCloud.cs" file, point clouds are transformed to the world space as follows:

```
public void OnTangoPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData pointCloud)
{
    m_mostRecentPointCloud = pointCloud;

    // Calculate the time since the last successful depth data
    // collection.
    if (m_depthTimestamp != 0.0)
    {
        m_depthDeltaTime = (float)((pointCloud.m_timestamp - m_depthTimestamp) * 1000.0);
    }

    // Fill in the data to draw the point cloud.
    m_pointsCount = pointCloud.m_numPoints;
    if (m_pointsCount > 0)
    {
        _SetUpCameraData();

        DMatrix4x4 globalTLocal;
        bool globalTLocalSuccess = m_tangoApplication.GetGlobalTLocal(out globalTLocal);
        if (!globalTLocalSuccess)
        {
            return;
        }

        DMatrix4x4 unityWorldTGlobal = DMatrix4x4.FromMatrix4x4(TangoSupport.UNITY_WORLD_T_START_SERVICE) * globalTLocal.Inverse;

        TangoPoseData poseData;

        // Query pose to transform point cloud to world coordinates, here we are using the timestamp that we get from depth.
        bool poseSuccess = _GetDevicePose(pointCloud.m_timestamp, out poseData);
        if (!poseSuccess)
        {
            return;
        }

        DMatrix4x4 unityWorldTDevice = unityWorldTGlobal * DMatrix4x4.TR(poseData.translation, poseData.orientation);

        // The transformation matrix that represents the point cloud's pose. 
        // Explanation: 
        // The point cloud, which is in Depth camera's frame, is put in Unity world's 
        // coordinate system(wrt Unity world).
        // Then we are extracting the position and rotation from uwTuc matrix and applying it to 
        // the point cloud's transform.
        DMatrix4x4 unityWorldTDepthCamera = unityWorldTDevice * m_deviceTDepthCamera;
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

        // Add offset to the point cloud depending on the offset from TangoDeltaPoseController.
        if (m_tangoDeltaPoseController != null)
        {
            m_mostRecentUnityWorldTDepthCamera = m_tangoDeltaPoseController.UnityWorldOffset * unityWorldTDepthCamera.ToMatrix4x4();
        }
        else
        {
            m_mostRecentUnityWorldTDepthCamera = unityWorldTDepthCamera.ToMatrix4x4();
        }

        // Converting points array to world space.
        m_overallZ = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_pointsCount; ++i)
        {
            Vector3 point = pointCloud[i];
            m_points[i] = m_mostRecentUnityWorldTDepthCamera.MultiplyPoint3x4(point);
            m_overallZ += point.z;
        }

        m_overallZ = m_overallZ / m_pointsCount;
        m_depthTimestamp = pointCloud.m_timestamp; //m_timestamp is the time of capture of point cloud

        // For debugging
        if (m_updatePointsMesh)
        {
            // Need to update indices too!
            int[] indices = new int[m_pointsCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < m_pointsCount; ++i)
            {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            m_mesh.Clear();
            m_mesh.vertices = m_points;
            m_mesh.SetIndices(indices, MeshTopology.Points, 0);
        }

        // The color should be pose relative; we need to store enough info to go back to pose values.
        m_renderer.material.SetMatrix("depthCameraTUnityWorld", m_mostRecentUnityWorldTDepthCamera.inverse);

        // Try to find the floor using this set of depth points if requested.
        if (m_findFloorWithDepth)
        {
            _FindFloorWithDepth();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_overallZ = 0;
    }
```

I have tried to transform the touch positions from the screen space to the world space using Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(). I have also tried to transform all point clouds from the world space to the screen space. The displayed point clouds and touch positions are the same on the screen but the transformed values are completely different.

Is there anyone knows this problem? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In [TangoPointCloud.cs](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/920dc9d4a145ae681681ab75789b0e645a626d9c/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Scripts/TangoPointCloud.cs), `m_points` is populated with the latest point cloud in Unity world space.  Consequently, the simplest way to determine whether points fall within a given portion of the screen is to use Unity's [`Camera.WorldToViewportPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html) method to transform entries in `m_points` into viewport space (i.e. (0,0) is bottom left, and (1,1) is top right), and then check whether the given viewport point falls within your target area.

As an example, in the PointToPoint example that you mention, you could ignore all points that fall outside of the middle rectangle (i.e. half the width, half the height) of the screen by adding a simple check to `_WaitForDepth` before using the next selected point:

From [`PointToPointGUIController._WaitForDepth`](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/bd5f089a5f6f46121c69c0ae404737c3fd47b06e/AndroidIntegration/ModelColorPicker/Unity/ModelColorPicker/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/PointToPoint/Scripts/PointToPointGUIController.cs#L195):

```
if (pointIndex > -1)
{
    Vector3 screenPoint = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(
        m_pointCloud.m_points[pointIndex]);
    if (screenPoint.x > 0.25f && screenPoint.x < 0.75f &&
        screenPoint.y > 0.25f && screenPoint.y < 0.75f) {
        // Index is valid
        m_startPoint = m_endPoint;
        m_endPoint = m_pointCloud.m_points[pointIndex];

        m_distance = Vector3.Distance(m_startPoint, m_endPoint);
    }
}
```

Finally, to convert from [`Touch.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) which is in screen space (i.e. pixels) to viewport space, you can use [`Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint.html), and then you can compare these directly with the viewport coordinates of a depth point.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I will check and let you know the result.